# How to create custom validator in Asp.net using ActiveRecord

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, validation, customvalidator

i want to create custom validator for checking fields exists in multiple tables

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best way is to use the [Castle validator Component](http://hammett.castleproject.org/?p=114)

please see: [Simple server Side validation](http://blogs.taiga.nl/martijn/archive/2008/11/26/validation-in-asp.net-mvc-part-1-basic-server-side-validation.aspx) and [Custom Server Side validation](http://blogs.taiga.nl/martijn/archive/2008/11/27/validation-in-asp.net-mvc-part-2-custom-server-side-validation.aspx)